Unable to access an specific image on a local web server
This seems like a newbie question but it's driving me crazy. I'm updating a banner image on a web site I maintain but the new image refuses to display. I'm getting permission errors such as "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource." with the new image.

The image has the same permissions as every other image in the directory,
The image has the same ownership (<me>:www-data) as every other image in the directory, and
There are no access lists in use.

I know this because I have reset the permissions and ownership for the entire directory (chmod & chown) and removed the acls using setfacl -b *.
The file name is spelled correctly - I can type in the url of another image in the directory, which successfully displays, then cut & paste the image name from a file manager into the url to replace the image and I still get the access error. Moreover, if the name was misspelled, I'd get a "not found" error, not a permissions error.
The error doesn't even require a web page. I get it when I use http://<my local domain>/images/filename.png. It's happening with both Firefox & Chromium.
Can anyone suggest what the issue might be?
Thanks.

Is there a space or other problematic character in the file name?

if your distro has selinux enabled, make sure that file's context was set correctly (ls -Z)? Otherwise, check the webserver logs to verify it was unable to access the file, and not choking on some other kind of error (like if the OS thinks the file is still open/being written to). Double-check you didn't accidentally copy a link instead of a file (ls -la)

do you have any request filtering enabled, and if so, have you allowed .png files?

Thanks, but the answer is No to all of the above. There are no problematic characters, just regular letters - and I've retyped the name to make sure it doesn't contain some hidden character.  Selinux isn't installed. The only program that isn't letting me open the file is apache2. My apache2 setup is pretty basic and I can view other .png files.
Both the logs and Inspect Element show that it is unable to access the element.

Is this the only file you've updated this way, and have you already restarted apache? Clear your browser cache too if you haven't already. Also, try and read that image as the service account, like sudo -u apache cat /path/to/filename.png. Otherwise, take a look through the answers and comments out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/

Thanks Cpt Whate, but a restart of apache shouldn't be necessary. It also did nothing.  I've cleared the cache multiple times. There is no apache account but running your command gives me the same permission denied error.
Strangely, when I did another ls -l, the file showed as having no group permissions. However a couple of up-arrows showed that the command I'd run earlier `(chmod 664)', when the problem first showed, was correct. Re-running it fixed the issue.

I have no explanation for why the group permissions vanished but scrolling back through the bash buffer, I see it occurred when I ran setaclf -b *. The file had group rw access before then but lost it when the acl was removed.

The problem seems to be related to the use of Samba file sharing. The graphic element was on a Samba share at one point and had picked up an acl. When I copied it to the web server, the acl remained. For some reason, even though the file had group rw permissions for the www-data group, the acl was denying access to the file.
I'd had problems with acls before so I used my normal solution of simply wiping them (setfacl -b *) but failed to notice that this somehow removed the group permissions. I note that the man page says:
-b, --remove-all
Remove all extended ACL entries. The base ACL entries of the owner, group and others are retained.
Perhaps because the group changed from users to www-data when the file was copied, the group access rights got lost when setfacl was run.
